# ReportViewer control - axd url

Tags: c#, webforms, reportviewer

I've embedded `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer` control in my aspx. My site works on mysite.com.
When try for exmple to export report, there is new black window opened with address
`mysite.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd...` **It's working fine.**
But.. I would like to pass that axd via my proxy. I mean, I'd like to force export to use url
`myproxy.mysite.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd...` which will redirect request back to `mysite.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd...` 
I've noticed, that link is build within js (that is inlcuded in that axd):

```
ExportReport: function(format)
{
    if (this.ExportUrlBase == null)
        return false;
    window.open(this.ExportUrlBase + encodeURIComponent(format), "_blank");
    return true;
},
```

The url to axd is stored in `ExportUrlBase`. **How can i change it to my proxy serwer url?**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to modify the `ExportUrlBase` field in javascript. The report itself is stored in a placeholder somewhere on the page, once found you can create call _getInternalViewer() function on it to gain access to the ExportUrlBase. Have a look at the following code:

```
function ModifyExportUrlBase()
{
    var rv = null;
    var r = null;
    try
    {
        // get the report viewer
        rv = this.$find("ctl31");
        r = rv._getInternalViewer();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
        setTimeout(ModifyExportFileName, 2000)
        return;
    }
    if(r == null)
    {
        setTimeout(ModifyExportFileName, 2000);
        return;
    }
    else{
        r.ExportUrlBase = "/yourproxypath" + r.ExportUrlBase
    }
}
ModifyExportUrlBase();
```

The timeouts are necessary because the reports are received asynchronously and this will only work once the reports are fully loaded.

The `ctl31` was found using the inspect element feature on firebug to check the actual download link, there will be an onclick method which utilizes the ID of the report on the page. Other sites that I have looked at indicated that it may "`reportViewer`" if you are using Dynamic CRM. The easiest way to find out is to just check it with firebug or developer tools.

Unfortunately this is not a complete fix for your issue as ExportUrlBase does not store the entire URL, just the URL relative to the domain, ie, ExportUrlBase = "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd..." not "www.yoursite.com/Reserved.ReportViewer..." However, once you can change this, you can create a directory in your inetpub folder with new config and redirect the link through that folder to use that config.

Sources:

http://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-adding-date-to-exported-filenames/

https://www.dforge.net/2012/11/11/how-to-specify-a-filename-for-your-exported-reports-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the behavior of the ExportReports() function:

```
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._InternalReportViewer.prototype.ExportReport =
    function(){ return "/proxypath" + this.ExportUrlBase } 

    window.open(
        $find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport() + encodeURIComponent('CSV'), 
        "_blank" 
    );
```